# Как открывать Jar файлы в Linux Debian щелчком мыши? (без консоли)

Tags: linux, debian, jar

через консоль (java -jar name.jar и после одного дополения ./name.jar) открывается без проблем, а мышкой открывается только как архив.. хотелось бы иметь возможность открывать по щелчку как в windows, как реализовать такую возможность?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Binfmt_misc_for_Java

Comment: А, конкретно в дебиане уже есть пакет [jarwrapper](https://packages.debian.org/stable/jarwrapper), наверное можно просто его установить

Comment: я его установил и запуск упрощается до: ./имя.jar    но мышкой всё равно открывает как архив

Comment: А о какой конкретно «мышке» речь? Какая среда рабочего стола, какой файловый менеджер?

Comment: среда Gnome. Файлы — файловый менеджер по умолчанию для рабочего стола GNOME, также известный как приложение «Nautilus».

Comment: Если ваш Nautilus распозаёт его как Java-файл (application/x-java-archive), то наверное можно в свойствах файла «Открывать в программе» выбрать нужную программу (то есть Java) да и всё? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzUC3.png

Comment: дело в том, что из представленных там нет ничего, что открывает jar файлы

Comment: как добавить туда OpenJDK? наутилус распознаёт, но OpenJDK в списке программ для открытия нет, как у Вас

Comment: Странно, он вроде бы должен быть там по умолчанию. Как именно у вас установлен OpenJDK, из какого пакета или как?

Comment: openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-Debian-1deb11u1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: через менеджер пакетов Synaptic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В /usr/share/mime/application/ необходимо создать файл jaropen.desktop  c содержимым:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Jar Opener
# This is for opening files, not launching the notebook from a menu
NoDisplay=true
Exec=java -jar %f
Terminal=true
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;
```

Далее выполнить команду в консоли `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications`. После можно будет выбрать в списке программ для открытия Jar Open по-умолчанию и запускать мышкой .jar файлы.

Comment: Меня смущает момент, почему этого файла не существует в дебиане изначально (должен был автоматически появиться `/usr/share/applications/openjdk-17-java.desktop` или типа того)

Comment: ну да, странно..